# Dot net fortify Scanning

Tags: asp.net, fortify

Can I run fortify scan on my machine without Visual Studio Installation?
I mean by fulfilling the basic requirements. Currently when scanning the code via fortify there are errors like cannot locate ildasm.exe

MSBuild: [error]: Unable to locate the Microsoft .NET disassembler tool (ildasm). Please make sure you have Visual Studio .NET version 7.1 or greater installed along with the SDK. 
MSBuild: If ildasm is installed in a non-standard location, please provide the full path to ildasm in the fortify-sca.properties file as com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.  You will need the Windows .Net SDK or a copy of the files from a development box.  These files are typically located at `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` or similar.  I've set up automation on machines that do not have Visual Studio installed and I just copy these files to a suitable location.

Next, you need to alter `[FortifyInstallRoot]\Core\config\fortify-sca.properties` and add `com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath=[Path to the SDK files]` using forward slashes (/) and NOT back slashes (\).

Finally, you will need to add some registry keys so that Fortify knows where to look for .Net Framework assemblies:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1]
"CLR Version"="v2.0.50727"
"InstallDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 7.1\\Common7\\IDE\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0]
"CLR Version"="v2.0.50727"
"InstallDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\\Common7\\IDE\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0]
"CLR Version"="v2.0.50727"
"InstallDir"="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0]
"InstallDir"="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\"
"CLR Version"="v4.0.30319"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0]
"InstallDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\"
"CLR Version"="v4.0.30319"
```

Comment: What do you mean by [Path to the SDK files] does this mean path till bin ?

Comment: com.fortify.sca.IldasmPath = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v8.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/ildasm.exe

Comment: This is very useful, thanks. I was wondering if you know of a generic translate command that could be applied to all .Net projects? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no generic command because Fortify needs to know the proper CLR libs to use when scanning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exercise GUI option, you can use Audit workbench.

Open the project that you want to scan, it will show up all files that you want to include in scan.